# Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined --> const [filteredClient] = this.clients.filter(pt => pt.client_id === clientid);

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this ts code, this is a function that chack form my client_id

```
public clients: Client[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cs.getAllClients().subscribe(
      clients => {
        this.clients = clients;
        console.log(clients)
      }
    );}
      getName(clientid: string) {
        const [filteredClient] = this.clients.filter(pt => pt.client_id === clientid);
         if (typeof filteredClient !== 'undefined' && clientid === filteredClient.client_id) {
          console.log(filteredClient.clientName)
          return filteredClient.clientName;
        }
      }
```

I used this function in html code,

```
 <table class="bordered table-bordered" [mfData]=" sale | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage"
    [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
    <thead style="color:black; background:rgb(207, 235, 245);border:1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);">
      <tr>
          <th>
              <mfDefaultSorter by="client_name">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
        <th>
          <mfDefaultSorter by="sale_date">Data</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
        <td>{{getName(item.clientName)}}</td>
        <td>{{item.sale_date | date:'d/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

My client name doesn't display, also in console show this error Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.

Can you suggest me, what is the problem in this code?

Thanx in advance

Comment: You are trying to filter data before it's there

Comment: You trying to access `clients` before they loaded. For example hide `<tbody>` until `clients` are loaded.

Comment: The data are in getAllClients  clients

Comment: @IliaVolk how? Sorry, i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

`getAllClients` is an observable and hence is asynchronous.Your view gets loaded before the data is received within your subscribe callback.

You can do one of the below solutions:

set empty array initially to avoid undefined array.

```
public clients: Client[]=[];
```

second option use `*ngIf` in template.

```
<table *ngIf="clients" class="bordered table-bordered" [mfData]=" sale | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage"
```

Comment: Thnx for your ansuer. My client name doesn't display in html, and error is not displayed

Comment: does it show up in console log? you may have some other bug?

Comment: console.log(clients)--> only this show up in console  and this   console.log(filteredClient.clientName) -- no

Comment: So there must be an issue with the if statement. Also, `filter` returns an array of element but seeing how you use `filteredClient` you expect it to be just one. In that case I'd suggest to use `find` instead of `filter`

Comment: @msokrates I think that the problem is in html. I change    let client = this.clients.find(pt => pt.client_id === clientid); Nothing has changed

Comment: is the function actually called? does `mf.data` have data? you need to debug further

Comment: Can you debug the code and see what values for clientId and filteredClient you have and if they are what you expect? Also, in html you do `getName(item.clientName)` is `item.clientName` equivalent to the `client_id` property of the client object?